# Playing an alarm sound while device's media volume is off

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am creating a alarm kind of application.When I open a particular activity, I want to play a custom sound with alarm volume level of device. 
If device's media volume is off and alarm volume is on then my custom sound should play.

What have I already tried:

```
 private void playAlarmSound(String fileName) {
    MediaPlayer p = new MediaPlayer();
    AudioManager audioManager= (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
        int volumeLevel=audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        p.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        p.setVolume(volumeLevel,volumeLevel);
        afd.close();
        p.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    p.start();
}
```

But by this when media volume is on it is playing sound but when media volume is off it is not playing the sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading the alarm volume level but this doesn't mean that the audio will be played through that stream.

You need to build and set the [AudioAttributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes.html) on the MediaPlayer, indicating USAGE_ALARM.

In other words:

```
p.setAudioAttributes(
    new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
        .build()
);
```

Comment: Thanks jmart. It's working fine. but "setAudioAttributes" is only available above API level 21. What about below 21?

Comment: Before api 21 you need to use setAudioStreamType in MediaPlayer.